# How to properly rename all of the unnamed default constraint

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2014: I am dealing with a large production database that includes so many unnamed default constraints.

The unnamed default constraints cause many issues because they get a random name in every "DEV" or "QA" environment that I populate the database schema population scripts. The random default constraint names cause the SSDT schema compare/update scripts fails.

I need to properly name the production database's default column constraints to a proper name, so when I script the database schema, they don't get a random name.

I use the following query to get the list of unnamed default constraints:

```
select 
    t.name, c.name, d.name, definition 
from 
    sys.tables t   
join    
    sys.default_constraints d on d.parent_object_id = t.object_id  
join    
    sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id      
                  and c.column_id = d.parent_column_id
```

There are 100s of them :(

Is there any "safe" way to rename all of the unnamed default constraints to a proper name such that they do not consider 'unnamed' and do not get a random name in every environment?

I was thinking to expand above query and generate `sp_rename` statements. Since I am dealing with a production database, I wanted to find the safest approach.

What is the most reliable and safest approach to solve this problem?

Comment: go for it, generate those rename statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the script that worked for me:

```
select
    CONCAT
    (
        'exec sp_rename ',
        '   @objname = ''['+d.name+']''',
        ' , @newname =  ''DF_',t.name,'_',c.name,   '''',
        ' , @objtype = ''OBJECT'' ;'
    ), 
    t.name, c.name, d.name, definition 
from 
    sys.tables t   
join    
    sys.default_constraints d on d.parent_object_id = t.object_id  
join    
    sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id      
                  and c.column_id = d.parent_column_id
ORDER BY t.name
```

Just paste the result's 1st column into a new query windows, surround it with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `ROLLBACK` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename it using `sp_rename` using `@objtype = 'OBJECT'`

This works on objects listed in sys.objects which includes constraints